# SendGrid SMTP API

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid and PHP (CakePHP). My server does not have SMTP enabled. Do I need smtp on my server to use SendGrid's SMTP API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at SendGrid.

Our SMTP API example recommends using the Swift_SmtpTransport library, which makes low-level socket connections to end systems. When configured with our example, Swift connects to our systems to deliver your message, and won't require an SMTP service on your end.

Edit, Jun 20 2014 for new link:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html

Comment: Cool.  Glad to see the sendgrid guys monitor this. Anyway I have sendmail installed and trying to configure that right now to work with sendgrid...having trouble with AuthInfo:...

Comment: Follow up question: does using SMTP API (or SendMail like I use) actually reduce our server load too? Or is the WEB API better for that?

Comment: The web API has less overhead because it's a single payload and acknowledgement. Smtp has a lot more chatter before you ever get to the payload.

Comment: The link provided to the sendgrid php example above does not work- 404 error

Comment: @iandouglas, Can you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266668/sendgrid-noclassdeffounderror-using-sendgrid-java-jar and suggest me on what to do?

Comment: @VamsiChalla Sorry, not I'm not a Java dev, glad you got it sorted out though.