# SendGrid - NoClassDeffoundError using sendgrid-java.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lambda, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid for the first time. I have looked at other questions on SO, in this regard, but none worked for me.

I am using Eclipse and Amazon Web Services - Lambda.
The library i am using is https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java

My scenario is, i am using a Lambda function to send emails to users who have opted for email communication.

Here is my code:

```
                        Email email = new Email();
                        email.addTo(DEV_TO_EMAIL);
                        email.addToName("XXXXX");
                        email.setFrom(DEV_FROM_EMAIL);
                        email.setSubject("XX");
                        email.setText("sms_message");

                        try {
                            sendgrid.send(email);
                        } catch (SendGridException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                            if(DEBUG)
                                logger.log("Exception while sending Email");
                        }
```

Here is the Exception:

```
    Could not initialize class 

org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory at 

org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:493) at 

org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:149) at 

org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:138) at 

org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:114) at 

org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:726) at 

com.sendgrid.SendGrid.<init>(SendGrid.java:71) at 

xx.LambdaFunction.handleRequest(LambdaFunction.java:183) at 

xx.LambdaFunction.handleRequest(LambdaFunction.java:1)
```

I tried to follow this suggestion on SO, [Sendgrid Java Not working in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284213/sendgrid-java-not-working-in-maven), but it resulted in the same error as well.

Any suggestions on what to do? Let me know if you need anything else..

Comment: This class is a part of Apache HttpComponents - http://javasearch.buggybread.com/home.php?keyword=org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory. Please make sure that you have included this dependency in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried most of the solutions posted on SO, but couldn't get it to work. Finally, i switched to using SendGrid4j. This worked after adding httpclient, httpcore, httpmime along with gson, jackson-core, libraries.

link for sendgid4j - https://github.com/shunjikonishi/sendgrid4j